# How to achieve this animatied transition effect when selection changes?

Tags: iphone

(The title sucks. How to improve?)

[Animated selection http://www.clafy.com/images/mwsnap001.jpg](http://www.clafy.com/images/mwsnap001.jpg)

In the picture above, there are 5 items. Use gestures to change selected item. During selection changing, there is some kind of animation like the Dock of MacOSX(although not that fancy). After that, the selected item will be in the screen center and in a highlighted mode(like cycling through a series of image).

I don't have a clue to start. Can you give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to check UIView animations static methods...

**Animating Views**

- beginAnimations:context:
- commitAnimations
- setAnimationStartDate:
- setAnimationsEnabled:
- setAnimationDelegate:
- setAnimationWillStartSelector:
- setAnimationDidStopSelector:
- setAnimationDuration:
- setAnimationDelay:
- setAnimationCurve:
- setAnimationRepeatCount:
- setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:
- setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:
- setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:
- areAnimationsEnabled

Comment: Some ideas are emerging. Thanks.